# Difference Between Increment and appraisal

Tags: salary, human-resources, appraisal

Am facing a issue in my office. Which is the salary hike. one year have been completed in office for me. I asked HR about the salary increment. BUT he is saying like it will be done in Appraisal. Am confused over here increment and appraisal. So according to his point once a year only i will increment then what is a use of it. Am confused. I want to know like is there any difference between these and what is it?

Thanks and Appreciate you help :)

Comment: Go get a dictionary and look them up.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan yup i know it but i want to know what are all the difference not the meaning.

Comment: The difference is in the meaning

Comment: Most places only do pay raises once a year or less often (I worked at one company where no one got raises for two years running (when the ecomony tanked) and the third year only a very small group got raises, so the majority of employees went 4 years without a raise.) Why would you think you would get pay raises more often than that?

Comment: Recommend reopening because the actual question being asked is generic, and can be explained without reference to specific company regulations.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An 'Increment' is just a salary increase, usually one that comes to you automatically by virtue of just working for a year, or just as a 'cost of living increase'. Government salaries often come with an increment every year. There may also be a 'merit-based raise', which may be awarded together with or separately from an 'increment'. If they happen together the difference between them may be unclear,

An Appraisal is a review of your performance. An appraisal often results in a pay increase, and many companies tie the two together. Appraisals are often once a year, though they may be more frequent

What your boss means is that **you will only get a pay raise once your performance has been 'appraised',** probably be a formal process. After that is done, the company will decide how much extra they are going to pay you.

Answer (score -1):

An increment is a fixed progression on a pay scale - common in civil service jobs

Appraisal implies you get what the company wants to give you

Comment: "Appraisal implies you get what the company wants to give you" - umm, no. This is wrong.